# Order # 000000012 (The order confirmation email was sent) in localhost

Tags: magento-2.0, order-email

In Magento 2  email is not received  after order is placed.    How to fix that issue? am using in localhost and also i configure with SMTP still email will not received

Comment: did you check with sending test mails option in smtp configuration? Did you receive the mail?

Comment: No, i got error invalid username and password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will require to install third party smtp module to work email properly.Please install below module and put your gmail details(user name,password...) in admin.

https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmail-smtp-app